# Using Python ElementTree/ElementInclude and xpointer to access included XML files

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xinclude, xpointer

I have a 'main.xml' file that includes 2 'sub_x.xml' file. The include lines are using 'xpointer' to only point/include specific tags of the include xml's.  When I use ElementTree to determine if this worked correctly, it shows that the whole 'sub' xml files are being included and not just the tags I want. I am not sure if I am using xpointer incorrectly or ElementTree or ElementInclude does not support this. Here are the files:

------'main.xml'--------

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ModelInfo xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="sub_1.xml" xpointer="xpointer(//ModelInfo/Model)" parse="xml" />
    <xi:include href="sub_2.xml" xpointer="xpointer(//ModelInfo/Model)" parse="xml" />  
</ModelInfo>`
```

-------'sub_1.xml'------

```
`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ModelInfo>
  <Model ModelName="glow">
    <Variables>
     <Variable Alias="glow_val" Input="False" Output="True" />
    </Variables>
  </Model>
</ModelInfo>`
```

-------'sub_2.xml'------

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ModelInfo>
  <Model ModelName="sirpwr_b_supply8v1">
   <Variables>
    <Variable Alias="sirpwr_a_supplyecu_Snsr8vIstat" Input="True" Output="False" />
   </Variables>
  </Model>
</ModelInfo>`
```

I would like 'main.xml' to appear to ElementTree as:

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ModelInfo xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <Model ModelName="glow">
    <Variables>
     <Variable Alias="glow_val" Input="False" Output="True" />
    </Variables>
  </Model>
  <Model ModelName="sirpwr_b_supply8v1">
    <Variables>
     <Variable Alias="sirpwr_a_supplyecu_Snsr8vIstat" Input="True" Output="False" />
     <Variable Alias="sirpwr_b_supply8v1_qstat" Input="False" Output="True" />
   </Variables>
   </Model>
</ModelInfo>`
```

The script I am running to load the XML files and test is:

```
`tree = ElementTree.parse('main.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ElementInclude.include(root)
for element in root:
    print element.tag`
```

xpointer is not working because 'ModelInfo' is being copied over from the 'sub_x' xml files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ElementInclude`](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xinclude.htm) does not support all of XInclude. The `xpointer` attribute on the [`<include>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#include_element) element is ignored.

It does work the way you want it with [lxml](http://lxml.de) and the [`xinclude()`](http://lxml.de/api.html#xinclude-and-elementinclude) method:

```
from lxml import etree 

tree = etree.parse('main.xml')
tree.xinclude()
print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Note that the XPointer [`xpointer()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-xpointer/) scheme never reached the status of W3C Recommendation (it's still just a working draft). It has been implemented in libxml2 (the C library behind lxml) but almost nowhere else.

Comment: The [xpointer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-xpointer/) scheme was superseded by the [xpointer framework](https://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-framework/). xpointer framework is what xinclude [1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) and [1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude-11/) references.